# Http - Request send File via multipart/from-data

Tags: angular, http, multipart

I am new at the multipart topic. I want to send a http-Request with Angular that submits a formData.

My Code so far:

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 sendData(fileToUpload:File, json:File) {
        formData.append('File', fileToUpload);
        formData.append('JSON', json);
        return this.http
          .post(url, formData, { headers: this.getHeaders() });
 }

  private getHeaders(): HttpHeaders {
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers     = headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
      return headers;
  }
```

Is there something I miss or should this code work just fine?

Comment: This video helped me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkvqLNcJz3Y

Comment: What errors  are thrown?  Is your json variable  JSON.stringify  ed?

Comment: I am getting a Bad-Request Error - so there has to be something wrong with my body. 
No do I have to use JSON.stringify? (The formData-documentation says I can use a Blob or a string - and I am adding a File (which is a Blob - am I right?))

Comment: I would try removing that header. The use of Formdata sets that(see video)

Comment: @myName_Question it seems to be a while, how did you resolve your Bad request error? I'm running into the same issue. I can upload a file and a form separately, but it would be much better to submit the form and include the file into the same request. thanks.